# Can't use git in filr directory: error 'Function not implemented'

Tags: git

At my employer, filr is used to enable external access to network drives and the home directory (private drive at work).  I have installed a filr client (version 4.2.2) on my home computer, which synchronises the files in my home directory at work and at home.
I have now tried to use a git in one of the folders. I can initialise the git and the .git folder is also created, but as soon as I enter another command, like 'git status', I get the error message 'Function not implemented'.

Git works fine in all other folders on my computer. I have already asked the admin at work, but he couldn't help either.

error in git bash:

```
$ git status
fatal: failed to stat 'C:/Users/user1/Filr/Meine Dateien/Monografie': Function not implemented
```

error via git gui:

```
fatal: failed to stat 'C:/Users/user1/Filr/Meine Dateien/Monografie': Function not implemented
fatal: failed to stat 'C:/Users/user1/Filr/Meine Dateien/Monografie': Function not implemented
    while executing
"close $fd"
    (procedure "git" line 5)
    invoked from within
"git config --global --add gui.recentrepo $path"
    (procedure "_append_recentrepos" line 14)
    invoked from within
"_append_recentrepos [pwd]"
    (procedure "choose_repository::_do_open2" line 12)
    invoked from within
"choose_repository::_do_open2 ::choose_repository::__o1::__d"
    invoked from within
".buttons.next invoke "
    invoked from within
".buttons.next instate !disabled { .buttons.next invoke } "
    invoked from within
".buttons.next instate pressed { .buttons.next state !pressed; .buttons.next instate !disabled { .buttons.next invoke } } "
    (command bound to event)
```

Comment: After initially thinking this is a big typo, I realized that filr seems to be some enterprise file sharing system. It seems that whatever it provides for file synchronization doesn't implement all the necessary hooks for a file system (most likely: it doesn't support POSIX semantics for files). I'm afraid this is very much a filr problem and unless you find someone who has the same setup it's unlikely to be solved.

Answer (score 1):

Git requires a file system that provides POSIX semantics.  Even on Git for Windows, the configuration used by Git is designed to provide semantics as close as possible to the POSIX ones.

In this case, Git wants to perform a `stat` call, which is used to get metadata about the file.  This information, including the file size, is stored in the index to determine efficiently whether a file has changed or not so Git can avoid re-reading and hashing the file needlessly.

In your case, the file system you're using, which you said is backed by filr, doesn't expose this information.  In a POSIX environment, `stat` is an extremely common operation, and the fact that this functionality doesn't work is going to break virtually any tool relying on it.  You're going to need to figure out how to make filr expose a POSIX-compliant file system so that Git will work, or use a different file system.

Note that even if you do fix this particular issue, Git does rely on POSIX semantics for operations for correctness and data integrity.  Therefore, your best bet on Windows is to stick with NTFS and SMB or file systems accessed through WSL.  You definitely shouldn't use cloud storage file systems like Dropbox for Git data, nor should you use things like WebDAV which don't expose the proper semantics.